# How can I configure a test class for my controller to use Embedded Mongo?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, junit

Apologies if my question is too obvious, but I am new to Spring. I have two properties configuration files on my application. One that is called `application.properties` and has the configuration settings for my production database and one that is called `application-test.properties`, which stores information for my `Embedded Mongo` db which I run to test my application. I also have an repository class called `ExpertRepository.java` as shown below:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface ExpertRepository extends MongoRepository<Experts, String>{
    Experts findBy_id(ObjectId _id);

}
```

To test my repository I have written the following class which runs the integration tests using the `application-test.properties` file, so my Embedded Mongo db:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
public class ExpertRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExpertRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testSaveAndFindExpert() throws Exception {

        ... } }
```

Now I wanna test my controller class and to do so I wanna use the EmbeddedMongo database which I have specified for testing purposes. This is how my `ExpertControllerTest.java` class looks right now:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ExpertController.class)
class ExpertControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private ExpertRepository expertRepo;


    Experts demoExpert = new Experts(ObjectId.get(),"Steve Jobs", "Enterpreneur",
                                     Availability.BUSY, Language.CHINESE);


    @Test
    public void getExperts() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/experts/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

    }
```

How could I connect this class with my Embedded Mongo and perhaps prepopulate it with some data to test my rest methods? Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 2.x and include in your gradle

testImplementation "de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo"

the binding between you test and the test instance of mongo should be automatic

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using two datasources , one each for production and test environments. Since you have already used filename as application-test.properties, you will need to set the profile to test programatically while running the test class.

Answer (score 0):

I up-voted the answer from [iltera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5012326/iltera)

But here is a test I wrote just to prove it works, you don't need anything else just the "de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo" dependency, good example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb):

```
@DataMongoTest
public class MongoApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assertNotNull(mongoTemplate);

        DBObject objectToSave = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("key", "value")
                .get();

        mongoTemplate.save(objectToSave, "collection");

        assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(DBObject.class, "collection")).extracting("key")
                .containsOnly("value");
    }

}
```